# Can I see who downvotes my questions/answers?

Tags: support, down-votes

Can I see who downvotes my questions/answers? Sorry if noob question...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot. Votes (up or down) are anonymous.

Reference: [Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @zaq's great answer, you seem to have received only three downvotes so far and two of them were cast even before you gained any reputation to lose.

I know it's annoying and you want to know who downvoted your post, but nobody, including a moderator, has an access to this information unless they investigate a serial downvoting.

If you suspect a user is serially downvoting your posts, you can flag one of your own answers for **in need of moderator intervention** and ask for investigation. I wouldn't mind getting a few downvotes per day, though.

Related Meta questions:

[What can I do if I'm the victim of serial downvoting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28756/what-can-i-do-if-im-the-victim-of-serial-downvoting)

[What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: Thanks. It's was not about serially downvoting, I just thought the downvotes were a lil bit ilogical. :) Peace.